# Sony Camera Remote API, Sony A7RII SSID - where to find Wifi Password?

Tags: android, camera, sony

Just got a Sony A7Rii but cannot find the SSID / Wifi password, it is not documented or provided as per QX-1 & other Sony Wifi camera devices.

https://us.en.kb.sony.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/36940/~/where-is-the-id-and-password-for-my-camera...

- say's look in WIFI_INF.TXT file in PMHOME/INFO folder on the device, but that file is missing (!)

I need the SSID / Wifi password in order to use the Sony Remote Camera SDK / API from an Android device.

Comment: Found it ! See the following YouTube Video for the full explanation - https://youtu.be/bG4ESlmv6Uc

Answer (score 0):

See the following Youtube video for details about how to obtain the SSID & Wifi password for the Sony A7Rii Wifi enabled camera - https://youtu.be/bG4ESlmv6Uc

After selecting the SSID & entering the correct Wifi password on an Android device, the Sony Remote Camera API can then be used to connect & control the camera remotely.